# Kafka Streams Serdes for Generic type

Tags: java, serialization, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, avro

I wrote a Serde for Kafka streams. My Serde class has generic type. It works fine when I explicitly pass it in an API method (overriding the default) but it doesn't work when I specify it via the `Properties` to set it as default.

So I look up the [docs](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/streams/developer-guide/datatypes.html#kstreams-data-types-and-serialization) and it indeed tells me I cannot do this:

> If a `Serde` is specified via `Properties`, the `Serde` class cannot have generic types, i.e., a class `MySerde<T extends Number> implements Serde<T>` cannot be used. This implies that you cannot use any `Serde` that is created via `Serdes.serdeFrom(Serializer<T>, Deserializer<T>)`. Only fully typed `Serde` classes like `MySerde implements Serde<MyCustomType>` are supported due to Java type erasure.

Ok, fine. However there is [SpecificAvroSerde](https://github.com/confluentinc/schema-registry/blob/master/avro-serde/src/main/java/io/confluent/kafka/streams/serdes/avro/SpecificAvroSerde.java) which works just fine when specified in the `Properties` like so:

```
streamsConfiguration.put(StreamsConfig.VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, SpecificAvroSerde.class);
```

Here's the first few lines of the class definition from GitHub

```
public class SpecificAvroSerde<T extends org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificRecord> implements Serde<T> {
  private final Serde<T> inner;

  public SpecificAvroSerde() {
    inner = Serdes.serdeFrom(new SpecificAvroSerializer<T>(), new SpecificAvroDeserializer<T>());
  }
```

Isn't that a direct contradiction of the documentation? Why is it that `SpecificAvroSerde` works just fine when specified as default in the `Properties`?